# Ubuntu Shell Script to Log where Certain Filetypes are Located

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to make a shell script in Ubuntu that will delete all media files and log where they are located. So far, here is the section of my deleter script:

```
sudo find / -name '*.mp3' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.mov' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.mp4' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.avi' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.mpg' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.mpeg' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.flac' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.m4a' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.flv' -type f -delete
sudo find / -name '*.ogg' -type f -delete
sudo find /home -name '*.gif' -type f -delete
sudo find /home -name '*.png' -type f -delete
sudo find /home -name '*.jpg' -type f -delete
sudo find /home -name '*.jpeg' -type f -delete
```

And here is my log file creator:

```
#!/bin/bash
#Creating a log file for contraband media files
echo "Creating Log file in Documents folder for Illicit Media Files."
touch newfile ./Documents/Illicitmedia.txt
```

Both of these work, however, what I want to do is have the first program find any media files (which are prohibited) and echo the file location of each to the `Illicitmedia.txt` logfile.

Basically:

1. I run a script that creates `Illicitmedia.txt` in the `./Documents` folder.
2. I run a script that finds all media files, and then echoes all the filepaths to the log file in a format like: `Illicit file found in: /home/user/Pictures/Photo.jpg`
3. Then, after each media file is logged, my other script will go through and delete the contraband files.

So in conclusion, the only step I still need help with is step 2. Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: Too much information for this question. Why not just ask for #2? Do something simple like this  sudo find /dir -type f -printf /tmp/myLog.log 2>&1 then read thru the file to delete one by one

Answer (score 1):

Here, I just made the first line for you to show you the concept, please apply the concept to the rest of your script:

```
sudo find / -name \*.mp3 -type f -print >> /tmp/log && sudo find / -name \*.mp3 -type f -delete
```

Your log will be stored at /tmp/log, and you may copy that at the end to wherever you want. If you really need every line of the log to say "Illicit file found in:" before the file path, then run the following after the log is finished:

```
sed -i -e 's/^/Illicit file found in: /' /tmp/log
```

Answer (score 1):

All the described operations can be done in two `find` commands:

```
log='./Documents/Illicitmedia.txt'

sudo find / -type f \
  -regex '.*\(mp3\|mov\|mp4\|avi\|mpg\|mpeg\|flac\|m4a\|flv\|ogg\)$' \
  -exec printf "Illicit file found: %s\n" >> "$log" {} + \
  -exec rm {} +

sudo find /home -type f -regex '.*\.\(gif\|png\|jpg\|jpeg\)$' \
  -exec printf "Illicit file found: %s\n" >> "$log" {} + \
  -exec rm {} +
```

Due to the plus character in expression `rm {} +`, the command line is built by appending each selected file name at the end, and the total number of invocations of the `rm` command will be much less than the number of matched files: `rm file1 file2 file3 #...`.

The regular expressions match any characters (`.*`) followed by dot and one of the extensions joined with the [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html). The `$` character is an end-of-the-line anchor.

**Using *OR* operator**

By the way, you might group the `-name` options using *OR* operator as follows:

```
sudo find / -type f \( \
  -name '*.mp3' -o \
  -name '*.mov' -o \
  -name '*.mp4' -o \
  -name '*.avi' -o \
  -name '*.mpg' -o \
  -name '*.mpeg' -o \
  -name '*.flac' -o \
  -name '*.m4a' -o \
  -name '*.flv' -o \
  -name '*.ogg' \
  \) # ...
```

**Alternative: single Bash invocation for each `find`**

It is possible to join both `-exec`'s into single Bash script:

```
cmd='printf "Illicit file found: %s\n" "$0" "$@" >> "'"$log"'" && rm "$0" "$@"'

sudo find / -type f \
  -regex '.*\(mp3\|mov\|mp4\|avi\|mpg\|mpeg\|flac\|m4a\|flv\|ogg\)$' \
  -exec bash -c "$cmd" {} +

sudo find /home -type f -regex '.*\.\(gif\|png\|jpg\|jpeg\)' \
  -exec bash -c "$cmd" {} +
```

Since `$@` expands to the positional parameters, starting from one, we need to pass `$0` as well (the effect of `-c` option). The `find` commands above execute four commands in total, e.g.:

```
printf 'Illicit file found: %s\n' testdir/x/y/z/file.mp3 testdir/a/b/two.mpeg testdir/a/b/c/one.mp3 testdir/a/one.avi testdir/a/one.mp4 testdir/a/x.flv
rm testdir/x/y/z/file.mp3 testdir/a/b/two.mpeg testdir/a/b/c/one.mp3 testdir/a/one.avi testdir/a/one.mp4 testdir/a/x.flv
printf 'Illicit file found: %s\n' testdir/m/xfile.png testdir/a/b/y.jpg 'testdir/a/b/c/a b c.jpg' testdir/a/b/one.png testdir/a/x.gif
rm testdir/m/xfile.png testdir/a/b/y.jpg 'testdir/a/b/c/a b c.jpg' testdir/a/b/one.png testdir/a/x.gif
```

*(you can figure it out by putting `set -x &&` at the beginning of `cmd`)*

**sudo**

I recommend getting rid of `sudo` in the script, and using it only when the script is launched, since `sudo` has a password prompt timeout for the *sudoers* security policy (the default value is 5 minutes).

**Further simplification**

Consider using `rm`'s `-v` (verbose mode) option instead of manually printing the files being removed, e.g.: `rm -v $path`.